# How can I optimize a query that loops over each day of a month or loops over a given date range?

Tags: arrays, laravel, algorithm, performance, data-structures

The following function is called 3 times from a controller with different parameters. Each time 30/31 queries are running according to the dates in a month. In the index page this single function is making 90-93 queries in a single page. How can I optimize it?

```
function attendanceData($dates, $status_id, $department = false)
{
    $attendanceresult = [];
    foreach($dates as $date)
    {
        if($department)
        {
            $presents = Attendance::with('Employee', function($q) use($department)
                                    {
                                        $q->where('department_id', '=', $department)
                                            ->where('designation_id', '!=', 26);
                                    })
                                    ->whereDate('in_time', $date)
                                    ->whereIn('attendance_status_id', $status_id)
                                    ->count();
        }
        else
        {
            $presents = Attendance::with('Employee', function($q)
                                    {
                                        $q->where('department_id', '!=', 4);
                                    })
                                    ->whereDate('in_time', $date)
                                    ->whereIn('attendance_status_id', $status_id)
                                    ->count();
        }

        if($presents)
        {
            $attendanceresult[] = $presents;
        }else
        {
            $attendanceresult[] = 0;
        }
    }

    return $attendanceresult;
}
```

The function is called with the following parameters:

```
$absentresult = attendanceData($dates, [4], $department = false);
$totalPresentResult = attendanceData($dates, [1, 2, 3, 5], $department = 3);
$totalAbsentResult = attendanceData($dates, [4], $department = 3);
```

Here I'm including a screenshot from PHP debugger:
[image]

One more thing to note here is I need the data in an array with each days data in an individual `key => value` pair

```
array:10 [
 0 => 7
 1 => 0
 2 => 7
 3 => 8
 4 => 3
 5 => 12
 6 => 13
 7 => 12
 8 => 0
 9 => 12
]
```

How can I Minimize the number of queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use wherein method for all dates in single query without using foreach loop

Comment: In that case it will return total data count of  those days. How can I  get that days specific data like: array:10 [
 0 => 7
 1 => 0
 2 => 7
 3 => 8
 4 => 3
 5 => 12
 6 => 13
 7 => 12
 8 => 0
 9 => 12
]